# Magento doesnt send any Mails out

Tags: magento-1.9, debugging

My Magento wont send Mails out and i see this Error in the /var/exception.log:

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Ungültiger Blocktyp: Mage_Imprint_Block_Field' in /homepages/42/d544673642/htdocs/magento/app/Mage.php:543
Stack trace:
#0 /homepages/42/d544673642/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Ung\xC3\xBCltiger Blo...')
#1 /homepages/42/d544673642/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('imprint/field', Array)
#2 /homepages/42/d544673642/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php(169): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('imprint/field', NULL, Array)
#3 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter->blockDirective(Array)
#4 /homepages/42/d544673642/htdocs/magento/lib/Varien/Filter/Template.php(163): call_user_func(Array, Array)
#5 /homepages/42/d544673642/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php(548): Varien_Filter_Template->filter('{{block type="i...')
#6 /homepages/42/d544673642/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(530): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter->filter('{{block type="i...')
#7 /homepages/42/d544673642/htdocs/magento/app/code/community/Mage/Advancedsmtp/Model/Email/Template.php(48): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->getProcessedTemplateSubject(Array)
#8 /homepages/42/d544673642/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(508): Mage_Advancedsmtp_Model_Email_Template->send(Array, Array, Array)
#9 /homepages/42/d544673642/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Mailer.php(84): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->sendTransactional('8', 'sales', Array, Array, Array, '1')
#10 /homepages/42/d544673642/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1354): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer->send()
#11 /homepages/42/d544673642/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1369): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->queueNewOrderEmail(true)
#12 /homepages/42/d544673642/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(139): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->sendNewOrderEmail()
#13 /homepages/42/d544673642/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->emailAction()
#14 /homepages/42/d544673642/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('email')
#15 /homepages/42/d544673642/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#16 /homepages/42/d544673642/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#17 /homepages/42/d544673642/htdocs/magento/app/Mage.php(627): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#18 /homepages/42/d544673642/htdocs/magento/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#19 {main}
```

in the system.log is see this error:

```
2015-01-27T09:40:57+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Illegal offset type  in /homepages/42/d544673642/htdocs/magento/lib/Zend/Mail.php on line 574
```

Does anybody know what this means? I cant handle this. Please help me with a tip.

Thanks

Tamás

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your email template you have this

```
{{block type="imprint/field"...}}
```

that does not map to anything.
Either you had an extension and disabled it or this shouldn't be there.
Remove that line and try again.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <magesetup>
            <class>FireGento_MageSetup_Block</class>
        </magesetup>
        // Add below block
        <imprint>
            <class>FireGento_MageSetup_Block</class>
        </imprint>
    </blocks>
</global>
```